# How to approve or give permission to access your tokens? Solidity /Metamask?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, metamask, ethereumjs

I'm currently creating a Dex which needs 1inch permission to access the users to tokens/funds.

e.g [image: Dex Permission(1inch)]

The problem is permission doesn't show up but instead shows 'contract deployment':

[image]

my current is code is:

```
interface IA {

function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    
}

contract A {

address private API = 0x111111111117dC0aa78b770fA6A738034120C302;

function approveTrans()  external returns( bool ){
IA(API).approve(0xb0BA561e95caEe425970D51dE8D55F653D08f86E,1000000000000000000  );
 
  return  true;
    
}

}
```

Regards Dee

Comment: You first have to deploy a contract, only then you can call methods on it. I suggest you go through a beginner tutorial like the [Hardhat tutorial](https://hardhat.org/tutorial).

Comment: Thanks for responding, but should I deploy the 1inch contract first then use that contract address in my contract where I would get the method?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `approve` function and on metamask it shows as "contract interaction". But on your screenshot it shows as "give permission to access.....". So, if you want the same effect, maybe it is not related to `approve` function but it might be related to metamask RPC API:

https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#restricted-methods

In any case, as @PaulRezvanBerg has commented, you first need to deploy the contract. Then you can create a frontend for it and then you can call the functions and also play with metamask rpc api.

By the way, this is not a final answer to your question. I hope somebody can share the code which prompts metamask with the message "Give permission to...."

Comment: Thanks Abdul for your reply, yes the challenging part is metamask not having a RPC url for giving permission. A custom rpc might be implemented but I still research and figure out how to overcome this.